# Finding height of tree without using list

Tags: python, recursion, tree, height

```
def height(t):
''' (Tree) -> int

Return 1 + the number of nodes in longest path in Tree t.

>>> tree = Tree(23)
>>> height(Tree)
1
>>> tree = descendents_from_list(Tree(11), [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)
>>> height(tree)
3
'''
num = 1
for i in t.children:
    if i.children:
       num += height(i)
return num
```

For the above function with t.value and t.children, I need to figure out how to find the height WITHOUT using a list. Like I need to find a way to recursively go further down the tree without keeping track of parent trees.

I've tried it, but I can't figure it out. Can someone please help me out with this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is this, the height of a tree is determined by the longest path in a tree. So if we are looking at a node with children, any node, which child node's height do we want to pay attention to? The child node with the *highest* height, correct? In Python, we can get the highest value of any iterable set of values using the built-in `max` function. At every point along the way, we want to add 1 to the maximum height amongst all of the children subtrees.

So now we just need a base case for the recursion, i.e. what do we do if a node has no children? Just return 1.

The following code illustrates this algorithm:

```
def height(t):
    if not t.children:
        return 1
    else:
        return max(height(c) for c in t.children) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a function for this like

```
num = 1
def height(t):
    global num
    child = [i for i in t if i.children]
    if child:
        num += 1
        height(child) #reccursing
    else:
        return num
```